# Lightbox forward nav arrow dropping below after first image

Tags: html, css, lightbox2

I'm having a strange issue with lightbox2. After navigating past the first image in my div the forward arrow drops below the image and the close button doesn't close image, instead it navigates forward in the images.

[image: Nav arrow first pic]

[image: nav arrow second pic]

I don't if it's a problem with using columns to display the pictures or what.

HTML

```
<div id="masonryWrapper">

    <div id="masonryWrapper">
      <div class="masonry">
        <a href="img/work/DSC00967 (2014_10_01 00_23_54 UTC).jpg"data-lightbox="photography">
           <div class="item"><img src="img/work/DSC00967 (2014_10_01  00_23_54 UTC).jpg">
           </div>
        </a>
        <a href="img/work/DSC01365 (2014_10_01 00_23_54 UTC).jpg"  data-lightbox="photography">
          <div class="item"><img src="img/work/DSC01365 (2014_10_01 00_23_54 UTC).jpg">
          </div>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 1em; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-gap: 1em; /* Firefox */
column-gap: 1em;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 1em;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;

}

.item img
{
width: 100%;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
vertical-align: top;

}

.item:hover img
{
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.item:after
{
content: '\A';
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
opacity: 0;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}

.item:hover:after
{
opacity: 1;
}

#masonryWrapper
{
max-width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10%;
overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Please remove the php part from your code as it isn't relevant at all, keep only the html, add the relevant javascript code and decide which version of lightbox you use... You added two tags there.

Comment: @Dekel The PHP shows how my divs are set up, which I think is very relevant. Unless, you're suggesting I post the HTML the PHP spits out? Their is no js other than the JS from the lightbox script. I'll be leaving the lightbox tag since the description says the following - Lightbox, and the newer **Lightbox 2**, is a JavaScript application used to display large images using modal dialogs.

Comment: Yes, it's better to show the html that your php code generates. Regarding the javascript - I think you should init the lightbox. It's not just the inclusion of the js file...

Comment: @Dekel This initializes the script according to the lightbox website- <a href="img/work/DSC01365 (2014_10_01 00_23_54 UTC).jpg"  **data-lightbox** ="photography"> And, obviously the lightbox is running so that's not the problem.

Comment: Did you include a link to the jquery library? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a padding issue in the lightbox.css

I changed the padding to 0 on the following two classes-

```
.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The padding was causing it to push out of the div and down below.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I am not seeing the nav buttons at all, and the addition of the padding setting didn't make a difference.

Comment: I'd open firebug or a similar program and take a look at your layout. You may have some other css adding padding to the div or img and affecting the arrows.It could also be something off with the hover state.

Comment: It turns out, after a lot of searching on the web, that I missed something in the setup for mine. The images were not in the correct folder. Once I put them in the root/images folder, it worked perfectly. Thanks.